# How to use $.inArray to validate against a field in an array object

Tags: jquery

I would like to check against an array with a field called name and check if a object.name in "arraryCollection" exist in "people array", if doesn't exist it will push "arraryCollection[n].name. Something like that.

```
$.each(arrayCollection, function(i, el) {    
    if ($.inArray(el.name, people.name) === -1) {
       people.push({name: el.name);                                  
    })
})
```

However I can't use people.name as it's undefined, and 
**below is what I done to work around**
, but is there a way to call people.name directly?

```
var tempList=[];
var people=[];
$.each(arrayCollection, function(i, el) {    
        if ($.inArray(el.name, tempList) === -1) {
           tempList.push(el.name);                                  
        })
    })
$.each(tempList, function(i, tl) {
    people.push({name: tl})
})
```

In other words, how do I call whole collection of array field directly like people.name instead of individually people[n].name which only returns 1 result.

Comment: Something is wrong here. If `people.name` exists then `people` is an object and you can't push to `people` because it is an object not array. Need more details about `people` structure. See [mcve]

Comment: people is an array that looks something like `people=[{name:"abc"},{name:"efg"}]` so `people[0].name` is `abc`

Comment: You have to loop through the array to compare name property of each object.

Answer (score 0):

Check inArray like this:

`inArray` returns the index of the element in the array, not a boolean indicating if the item exists in the array. If the element was not found, -1 will be returned.

```
// it will check if ABC is there in array `people.name`
if($.inArray("ABC", people.name) !== -1) {
   people.push({name: "testing"});                                  
}
```

Comment: please add some explanation :))

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili i am already editing my post for explanations :)

Comment: My problem is actually people.name, you can't just call people.name like that it will return undefined, as it's suppose to be people[n].name.

Answer (score 0):

The `$.inArray()` method is similar to JavaScript's native `.indexOf()` method in that it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match. If the first element within the array matches value, `$.inArray()` returns 0.

```
var testArr= [ 4, "ABC", 8, "John" ];


if($.inArray( "ABC", testArr) > -1 )
{
  console.log('Horray');
}
```

If you have a js object that has a key 'name' containing an array as value, then you can use it as you stated in your question:

```
var obj= {"name":[ 4, "ABC", 8, "John" ]};


if($.inArray( "ABC", obj.name) > -1 )
{
  console.log('Horray');
}
```

The `push()` method adds a new item to an array and not an object, make sure to use it only with arrays.